# Access 2013:Trying to write macro to update form fields from a query result

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a macro to update the value of a field in a form based off the results of a query.

I am entirely new to working with vba in Access so I apologize if I am asking a basic question.

I should mention, the "test" query returns exactly one result. It is essentially used similarly to a VLookup.

Currently My code is thus:

**Private Sub UpdateBasic_Click()**

**Dim bucket As String**

**DoCmd.OpenQuery "test", acViewNormal, acReadOnly**

*'this line is meant to record the result of the query into a variable. It is not working but I haven’t found the right command to get it to pick up the data yet.*

**bucket = A1**

**DoCmd.Close acQuery, "test", acSaveNo**

**DoCmd.OpenForm "BasicData", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal, "Global_ID = 'sdkfa'"**

*'this line is meant to update the value of the field on the form.*

**DoCmd.SetProperty testfield, acPropertyValue, bucket**

**End Sub**

I am having no luck getting the SetProperty command to work at all. It is consistently telling me I have a data type mismatch regardless of whether I try to give it a variable like bucket or a value like 10. Error message is as follows:
Run-time error ‘2948’:
An Expression you entered is the wrong data type for one of the arguments.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: See if the [DLookup Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) makes your problem easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to assign the result of a query to the value of a field in a form, I'd recommend a DLookup() function. You can use it like this (assuming the form's control is a textbox):

```
Me.TextBox.Value = DLookup("FieldName", "QueryName")
```

More elaborate solutions would involve recordsets, etc. but if you're looking for a quick, simple solution this should do just fine. Hope that helps!